# Find the real values of x and y for which the following equation is satisfied.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\dfrac{(1+i)x-2i}{  3+i}  + \dfrac  {(2-3i)y+i}{3-i}=i $$

$$ \dfrac{4x+2xi+9y-7yi+i+11}{10}=i  $$

This is where i stop and i dont how to continue to find $x$ and $y$ values because i'm bit confused with the question.

Comment: From the way it is written it is impossible to know which equation you mean. What belongs to the numerator, what belongs to the denominator? Please use LaTeX or at least brackets to clarify.

Comment: Can someone help to edit my post because i just started using this thing yesterday and dont know how to make it to become faction

Comment: @Ryan If you write your equation in dollar signs, it will be formatted nicely. Also, use `\frac` to make a fraction, so if you write `$$\frac{ax + by}{xc + dy} + \frac{x}{y} = i$$` you will get $$\frac{ax + by}{xc + dy} + \frac{x}{y} = i$$

Comment: That is all you need to know to edit your equation on your own, so I suggest you try it now. You will get a lot more answers to your question once people will immediatelly know what you are asking.

Comment: I've tempted an edit. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

two complex numbers $a+ib$ and $c+id$ are equals iff $(a=c) \,\land\, (b=d)$.
So, reduce the two sides of your equation to this form and you find two equations  that , solved simultaneously, gives  $x$ and $y$.

---

**All this is correct supposing that $x,y$ ar real numbers.**

You have some algebraic mistake in your result. The correct calculation gives:
$$
4x+2xi+9y-7yi-3-13i=0
$$
reorder this result as:
$$
(4x+9y-3)+i(2x-7y-13)=0+0i
$$
so the solution is given by the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
4x+9y-3=0\\
2x-7y-13=0
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve it?

Comment: Im not very clear with the hint given, and i try to expand my solution and i get 4x+2xi+9y-7yi-9i+11=0 could anyone solve it for me or tell whether my method of doing it is correct or wrong?

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it can be usefull :)